# Python How to Print multiple data frames in the email body

Tags: python, html, pandas, email, dataframe

I've split the complete dataframe into multiple dataframes based on the coulmn values, i want to fetch these multiple dataframes in the HTML email body in tabular format , How can i achieve this, please advise

```py
df1 = finalcheck[finalcheck['Team'] == 'Automation']
print(df1)

df2 = finalcheck[finalcheck['Team'] == 'Enterprise']
print(df2)
```

```
    Resource       Team      Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri
19  Patric Jane    Automation S   S  L   L    S           
11  Joey Charlie   Automation L   W  S   L    S 


     Resource     Team      Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri
12  Igor Wilson   Enterprise S   S  L   L    S           
16  Micheal Darl  Enterprise L   W  S   L    S
```

i want to disply these dataframe tables in the html table one below the other.. please suggest

Comment: use `df.to_html()` to get table as `HTML`

Comment: i tried with the below 
html1 = df1.to_html()
html2 = df2.to_html()
x = [html1, html2]
HTMLBody = x[0]+x[1]

but the table format is defaulted,how can i customise the table style?? and importantly there should be some gap/space between the two dataframes tables one below the other in the email, please advise. 
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>Resource</th>
      <th>Team</th>
      <th>Mon</th>
      <th>Tue</th>
      <th>Wed</th>
      <th>Thu</th>
      <th>Fri</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

Comment: it is HTML so you can add one or many `"<br/>"` to have space between tables - `HTMLBody =  html1 + "<br/><br/>" + htm2`

Comment: see also documentation for [to_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) and [styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)

Comment: Thank You.. It Worked..